# How to connect to an RDS postgres DB through a bastion host using terraform?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, terraform

I have an RDS database running aurora-postgresql:14.5 and I'm trying to automate the DB users creation by using the PostgreSQL terraform provider.

I created an SSH Tunneling on the bastion host like this `ssh -L 5432:my-rds-instance:5432 my-bastion-hostname -i ~/.ssh/some-key -l ec2-user` so every time a connection hits the bastion host send it to the DB.

I'm using terraform cloud so I allowed terraform notification IPs in the bastion security group as mentioned [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cloud-docs/api-docs/ip-ranges)

I'm using this provider config:

```
provider "postgresql" {
  host            = "my-bastion-hostname"
  port            = 5432
  database        = "postgres"
  username        = "some-user"
  password        = module.db.cluster_master_password
  sslmode         = "require"
  connect_timeout = 15
}
```

When I try to apply I get this error:

```
postgresql_role.zapier_user: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
╷
│ Error: error detecting capabilities: error PostgreSQL version: dial tcp 3.217.240.190:5432: i/o timeout
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Does your tunnel work without TF? Did you try to connect to RDS by any other mean ?

Comment: Yeah, does it work without TF.